# Ajax rejeitando imagens em array byte

Tags: ajax, asp.net, imagem

Tenho um sistema feito em Asp.Net, utilizo como fonte de requisição o Ajax junto com o Jquery. Criei uma função que busca as imagens armazenadas no banco de dados, converte-as em byte array (isso via Asp.net). Ao buscar os arquivos, ele trás um Json com as informações já convertido em um byte Array. Até ai tudo bem, ele funciona perfeitamente se for 1 ou 2 fotos. Se o arquivo trouxer 3 ou mais fotos ele busca as imagens, mas na hora de processar os dados ele rejeita e dá erro, creio eu que seja pelo tamanho do arquivo. Como consigo solucionar isso, fazendo o Ajax processar as informações com tamanhos maiores ?

O trecho da função é este:

```
function buscarFotos(idSelecionado) {
    var data;
    var value = {
        codigo: idSelecionado
    }

try {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "././CONTROLE/VISTORIA/vistoria.aspx/buscarFotoAnaliseBycodigo",
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {

            if (response === "null") {

                alert("NENHUMA vistoria ENCONTRADA PARA OS PARÂMETROS INFORMADOS");
                return;
            }

            if (response.d === "null") {

                alert("NENHUMA vistoria ENCONTRADA PARA OS PARÂMETROS INFORMADOS");
                return;
            }

            data = response.d;

            data = $.parseJSON(data);

            if (data !== 0 && data !== "") {

                carregarFotosVeiculo(data.imagens);
            } else {

                throw new Error("OCORREU ALGUM PROBLEMA AO BUSCAR VISTORIAS.");
            }

        },
        error: function (response) {
            data = response.d;
            alert(data);

            throw new Error("OCORREU ALGUM PROBLEMA AO BUSCAR VISTORIAS.");

        }
    });

} catch (e) {

    alert(e);
}
```

}

Erro:

> mesaAnalise.js:721 Uncaught Error: OCORREU ALGUM PROBLEMA AO BUSCAR
>   VISTORIAS. at Object.error (mesaAnalise.js:721)  at u
>   (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)  at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith]
>   (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2) at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2) at
>   XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Lembrando que se for 1 ou 2 fotos o sistema não dá erro. Com 3 imagens ou mais ele dá este erro e não carrega os dados. Como posso resolver isso?